# Can I upgrade my graphics card?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

I have a Hp laptop, and was wondering if I can upgrade its dedicated gpu without breaking its warranty.
The graphics card that it has is pretty weak, I was playing bf3 all minimum at 23 fps.
The laptop model is hp pavilion 15-n268sa

Comment: No;  You cannot;  Your laptop uses a soldered solution and you have neither the skills to remove and install the GPU nor the equipment to do so without damaging the hardware itself.

Comment: Adding to what @Ramhound said, that laptop uses an APU which is a GPU joined onto a CPU so the full intent of the laptop is to be budget friendly. Since it is budget friendly I doubt HP would add a superfluous PCIe lane just for your convenience. The only possibility that you could have is to upgrade to a stronger APU but since it is soldered onto the motherboard, good luck not voiding the warranty let alone breaking the laptop beyond repair. The only advice I could give you at the moment is to lower the resolution of BF3 to something less than 1366x768

Comment: I didn't even notice it was a APU; I will have to change my comment from simply no to "no, there isn't even a GPU to switch out"

Answer (score -1):

Laptops aren't meant to have a gpu that you can upgrade. The laptop case is usually fit perfectly for the exact gpu that is put into the machine. The gpu is usually soldered onto the motherboard, making it a huge pain to remove. It's nothing like a simple pci slot such as with a desktop.

I would suggest building a desktop or getting a new laptop.